# How to fix auto-fixable problems on VSCode with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I've updated pedantic package and ended up 1K+ problems. Many of them are prefer_single_quotes or unnecessary this etc. They are one click away to fix. I think eslint or some other tools can do that within the VSCode.

Is there a way to do it with Flutter projects?  I find dartfix package but says “No recommended changes” after running it. What I want to do is fix all the auto-fixable problems on the problems tab.

[dartfix on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/dartfix)

Answer (score 35):

Not sure if you have tried the built in fixes using dart fix.

Use `dart fix --dry-run` to see suggested changes and `dart fix --apply` to apply them.

https://dart.dev/tools/dart-fix

Answer (score 15):

You can fix all the [Analysis issues identified by dart analyze](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-fix) on `save` of file.

Add this in `settings.json` file

```
{
    // ...
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": true
    },
}
```

Comment: where do we find the settings.json file?

Comment: Press `CTRL/CMD + p` & type `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`, press enter.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I tried all fixes listed on here, and the one that helped me the most was manually using the search and replace feature in VSCode. For example, if you have 500+ Invalid const value errors, just search for something like "const Text(" and replace it with "Text(" and all the errors with this error assorsiated with text will be gone... I just repeated this with other errors and then at the end, run:

```
dart fix --dry-run && dart fix --apply
```

and this got rid of my 500+ errors and most of the problems listed. Hope this works. Just get creative with your search and replaceAll phase...

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and tried dartfix. It worked for me when I specified the correct path:

`$ dartfix --pedantic lib/src/ --overwrite`

Went from ~450 problems to 59

Even though all of my files that I wanted to fix are in the src folder, I had to run the command again with `$ dartfix --pedantic lib/ --overwrite` to get my main file. That might be the issue that you're having, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how many of these problems `dartfmt` can cover, but it's definitely worth trying! To run `dartfmt` with idiomatic fixing, overwriting and link-following, please run `dartfmt --fix --overwrite --follow-links .` in your project folder.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. I've run this command but trivial fixes like "convert to single quoted string" was not applied.

Answer (score 0):

For fix all Analysis issues identified by dart analyzer, you can use the vscode flutter fix all command.

In your project folder, create a `.vscode/settings.json` file and add the following:

```json
{
    // ...
   "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": "explicit",
    },
}
```

Comment: that looks promising!