# Fix all const warning flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

How to fix this all const warning in VSCode? It's hard if I fix one by one.
[image]

Comment: https://dart.dev/tools/dart-fix I think this is what you need

Comment: I've tried it. But, didn't work.

Comment: `ctrl + .` -> "fix add const everywhere in file"

Comment: Thank for helping me. But, I've tried but only one line, not everywhere.

Comment: @cas Thanks, that worked for me, just wanted to add in order to get the menu 'fix add const everywhere', we need to select all the code using Ctrl+a(in windows) and Command+a (in mac os)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply right click on any of the warning in the problems tab in vscode and choose Add **const** modifiers everywhere in the file.
[image]
But you have to do it manually for all files in your project.

### Better solution:

Open Vscode : `settings` -> open `settings.json` file
Copy paste following lines

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true
 }
```

You can find the `settings.json` file  in 'C:\Users<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User'

Thats it,From now whenever you're saving a file it will apply the quick fix ( adding **const** in all places). All you have to do is just save your files.

### Note :

It will not only fix the **const** problem but also fixes some other lint warnings like removing **unused imports**.

Comment: is there any solution for Android Studio?

Comment: You can use the first option in my answer (Add const modifiers everywhere in the file).
Or you can try 'dart fix --dry-run' , 'dart fix --apply'. @MubasharHussain

Comment: why am I not seeing the "Add const modifiers everywhere in file" option?

Comment: @Chris if you have more than 1 of these warnings in a single file, then it should show up on a secondary mouse click. Kind of a long shot but, might it be because you don't right-click on one of the said const errors?

Answer (score 26):

If you want to add `const` everywhere in the code,  take a look at [dart fix](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/flutter-fix) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61708945/how-to-fix-auto-fixable-problems-on-vscode-with-flutter) is a similar question answered.

If you just want to hide all the warnings, you can add

`// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors`

anywhere in the file.

Or, if you want to get rid of it in all files, find `analysis_options.yaml` in the root of your project and set the property to false:

[image]

If there is no such file (`analysis_options.yaml`), you can [create](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options) one and set it to false.

Code the of image file:

```
  rules: 
    prefer_const_constructors : false
    file_names : false
    public_member_api_docs: false
    lines_longer_than_80_chars: false
    avoid_catches_without_on_clauses: false
    avoid_equals_and_hash_code_on_mutable_classes: false
    prefer_relative_imports: false
    type_annotate_public_apis: false
    avoid_types_on_closure_parameters: false
    sort_constructors_first: false
    prefer_generic_function_type_aliases: true
    unnecessary_lambdas: true
    use_key_in_widget_constructors: false
    avoid_print: false
```

Comment: I think he wants to put 'const' to everywhere. Not suppressing the warning.

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad :-(

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I prefer to add const not supress the warning const.

Comment: All const warnings: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_constructors_in_immutables, prefer_const_declarations, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

Answer (score 6):

See [Flutter Fix](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/flutter-fix)

To apply all changes in bulk, run the following command:

> dart fix --apply

Answer (score 4):

I'm Using visual Studio Code for Flutter app development. you can add

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true
 }
```

this to Settings.json file and Editor will auto add const and other fixes. for Find Setting.json you have follow this step

```
Ctrl + Shift + P -> Search Setting.json(Open User Settings.json) -> add above code.
```

Comment: This method didn't work, but dart fix --apply worked

Answer (score 3):

write it inside terminal
dart fix --apply
(it will takes some seconds and dart fix fixes deprecated lints in analysis_options.yaml files where possible, by:

removing them, or possibly
replacing them with another preferred lint)

Answer (score 0):

To apply all changes in bulk, run the following command:

| dart fix --apply